# Sum of three uniformly distributed random variables.

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be uniformly distributed $U(0,1)$. Then I know that the density function for the random variable $A= X+Y$ is 
$$f(a) = \begin{cases} 
      a & a\in (0,1)\\
      2-a & a\in[1,2)\\
      0 & \text{ otherwise} 
   \end{cases}.
$$
and 
$$
g(z)=\begin{cases}
   1  & z\in (0,1)\\
   0   & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
My goal is to find the $B = A+Z.$ By the convolution theorem:
$$h(b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(b-z)g(z)dz=\int_{0}^{1}f(b-z)dz.$$

After this I am not sure how to proceed. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Crucial assumption missing in the question is that $X,Y,Z$ are independently distributed.

Answer (score 1):

So we get 
\begin{equation}
f(b-z) = \begin{cases} 
      b-z & b-z\in (0,1)\\
      2-(b-z) & b-z\in[1,2)\\
      0 & \text{ otherwise} 
   \end{cases}. 
\end{equation}
We have that 
\begin{equation}
 0<z<1
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 b-1<b-z<b
\end{equation}
If $b < 0$, then $b - z < 0$, so $h(b) = 0$ according to the boundaries we have. On the other hand if $b - 1> 2$ (or $b>3$), that is is $b-z>2$, we also get $f(b) = 0$. Other than that, we can distinguish three cases:

**Case 1:**
If $0<b<1$
\begin{equation}
h(b)
=
 \int_{0}^{1}f(b-z)dz
 =
 \int_0^{b} b-z \ dz
 =
 \frac{b^2}{2}
\end{equation}

**Case 2:** If $1<b<2$
\begin{equation}
h(b)
=
 \int_{0}^{1}f(b-z)dz
 =
 \int_{b-1}^{1} b-z \ dz
 +
 \int_{0}^{b-1} 2-(b-z) \ dz
= \frac{b(2-b)}{2}-\dfrac{b^2-4b+3}{2}
\end{equation}

**Case 3:** If $2<b<3$, we have 
\begin{equation}
h(b)
=
 \int_{0}^{1}f(b-z)dz
 =
 \int_{b-2}^{1} 2-(b-z) \ dz
 =
 \frac{b^2-6b+9}{2}
\end{equation}

> **Distribution of B**
>   \begin{equation}
> h(b) = \begin{cases} 
>      \frac{b^2}{2} & b\in (0,1)\\
>       \frac{b(2-b)}{2}-\frac{b^2-4b+3}{2} & b\in(1,2)\\
>       \frac{b^2-6b+9}{2} & b\in(2,3)\\
>       0 & \text{ otherwise} 
>    \end{cases}. 
> \end{equation}

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I just didn't get why you would change the limits of integration from 0 to 1 to 0 to b in Case 1.

Comment: Hello @Hello_World, well you know, allowing $z$ to go from $0$ till $b$ is allowing $x$ in $f(x)$ to vary from $x = b-z = b-b = 0$  till $x = b-z = b-0 = b$. You need to cover all the case where $b - z \in [0,1]$, right ?